# HTML for list with dashes and custom font colour

Tags: html, css

I am finalising a Wordpress website, but my last challenge is to create a bullet list with dashes instead of dots - the dashes must also be in white to match the font colour.

I've tried a few answers here but nothing seems to work right!

Text and dashes must be white (as it's on a blue background)

– sustainable growth,

– increase profits,

– expand market share and

– improve efficiency

Comment: you should show current code, and its output for a better answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend you to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read about [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to fully understand the rules of this site and get some advice on asking a good question (that will increase your chances of getting a good answer) and will give you your first badge!

Comment: Great stuff! Will do :)

Comment: Two have my questions have been marked as duplicates by @dippas which  means I can't ask any more questions. I have update the questions explaining my challenges and why the other entries have not worked for me. I find the fact that questions are just randomly marked as duplicates without actually understanding the challenges as rather unhelpful and unfair. If this community this unwilling to help people who are learning then it should say something about that i.e. we are an elitist community with no patience for people who are beginners.

Answer (score 2):

Since the dash "–" is not a [supported value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type#Values) for bullet lists style type, you could use an image as Vinod suggested in his answer or –IHMO– use the `::before` [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) to simulate the required style for an easier solution.

```css
ul {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
  content: "– ";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>sustainable growth,</li>
  <li>increase profits,</li>
  <li>expand market share and</li>
  <li>improve efficiency</li>
</ul>
```

Another (cooler) solution (with [little browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=counter-style) yet) would be using [`@counter-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style) to define your own bullet style.

> Please note that if you are using production browsers this will only work in [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/). (Nov '17)

```css
@counter-style dash {
  system: cyclic;
  symbols: "–";
  suffix: " ";
}

ul {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  list-style-type: dash;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>sustainable growth,</li>
  <li>increase profits,</li>
  <li>expand market share and</li>
  <li>improve efficiency</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UL -> LI, then you can follow these steps:

1) Draw the hyphen in paint.
2) Save it as a png
3) In css, for your UL, you can apply this style:

```
ul {
  list-style-image: url('hyphen.png');
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:before` to display a hyphen.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
}
ul.hyphen {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.hyphen > li {
  text-indent: -10px;
}
ul.hyphen > li:before {
  content: "-";
  text-indent: -10px;
}
```

```html
Some text
<ul class="hyphen">
  <li>list 1</li>
  <li>list 2</li>
  <li>list 3</li>
</ul>
Last text
```